# How get a programmatically menu fields into template?

Tags: theming, 8, entities, navigation

i add to my main menu an image field programmatically for build a megaMenu :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info().
 */
function hook_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

    $fields = [];


    if ($entity_type->id() == 'menu_link_content') {


        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');

        $fields['image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
            ->setLabel(t('Image'))
            ->setDescription(t('Image field'))
            ->setSettings([
                'file_directory' => 'imagesMenu'. '/' . $year . '/' . $month,
                'alt_field_required' => FALSE,
                'file_extensions' => 'png jpg jpeg',
            ])
            ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                'label' => 'hidden',
                'type' => 'default',
                'weight' => 0,
            ))
            ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
                'label' => 'hidden',
                'type' => 'image_image',
                'weight' => 0,
            ))
            ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
            ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

After a drush update-entity, i can see the field on my form and i can add the image.

Now i try to get this field into twig.

When i use kint with keys this is the result :

> menu--main.html.twig

[image]

I cannot see my field image.

Any idea how can i get my field in tempalte ? hook_preprocess for the menu ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how i get my custom image field from menu into twig

```
function hook_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {

    if($variables['theme_hook_original'] == 'menu__main'){

            $items = $variables['items'];
            foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

                if(count($item['below'])>0)
                {
                    foreach($item['below'] as $id=>$array)
                    {
                        $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->loadByProperties(array('uuid'=>$array['original_link']->getDerivativeId()));

                        foreach($entity as $idMenu)
                        {


                            if($idMenu->get('image')->entity != null) {


                                $image = file_create_url($idMenu->get('image')->entity->getFileUri());

                                $items[$key]['below'][$id]['imageUrl'] = $image;


                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        $variables['items']=$items;

    }

}
```

I just work on my item menu and add 'imageUrl' into my array.
I first load my entity by properties with the UUID for access to my menu item fields.

This method is only for my sub menu ( inside my mega menu, i want just add an image by item in submenu )

> that why i check count(item['below']>0)

[image]

For now i can't find better way.

Comment: I just want to note that overall this worked, but I used this code to generate the final URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754661/drupal-8-images-with-image-style